# database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist - how to fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

a friend deployed my application on Heroku, and it works fine there. But I can not open my application on local server. Can anyone help?

When going on localhost i get the following error message:

ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError
FATAL: database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist

Extracted source (around line #661):

```
    rescue ::PG::Error => error
      if error.message.include?("does not exist")
        raise ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError.new(error.message, error)
      else
        raise
      end
```

Comment: `rake db:create && rake db:migrate`

Comment: I tried, and got this answer: rake db:create
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist

PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist

Comment: i don't know which adapter I use. Postgres, because it is what heroku runs on and sqlite, since its the db of ruby on rails - if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `database.yml`

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8

development:
  <<: *default
  database: your_app_development
  username: your_usernmae
  password: your_password
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing  database.yml file to actually be the names of the database you want to create like database: my_app_development 
ex:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: ***_development
```

You need to change database: and run `rails db:create`
then `rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`